# set the value of Image to nil SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have set a condition to load an SFsymbol.

```
Image(systemname : isShowList ? "ellipsis" : "")
```

But I am getting a warning `No symbol named ''`

How can I set this to an empty value without warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on what is needed in common layout, but possible variants are

a) remove image conditionally

```
if isShowList {
   Image(systemName : "ellipsis")
}
```

b) hide image conditionally

```
Image(systemName : "ellipsis")
  .opacity(isShowList ? 1.0 : 0.0)
```